# Is there a way to combine a outputstream and printwriter in one request?

Tags: java, file, sockets, input, output

I have to do a file transfer, in my case a pdf, through socket in java for my homework. Usually I requested text and got text back, but this time I have to send a file through socket. In my investigation I discovered that file transfers are made with Fileinput(output)streams. My problem is that the request to the server has to look something like this:

```
    File file = new File(pathToFile);
    Pirntwriter out = new PrintWriter(Socket s.getOutputStream());
    Outputstream outFile = s.getOutputStream();
    int count
    out.write("user file\r\n"
                + file.getName()+"\r\n"
                + file.length()+"\r\n"
                + "body\r\n");
    // send file but im not sure how
    byte[] buffer = new buffer with size of file.length()
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
         outFile.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    out.flush
    outFile.flush
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. In this way the server counts the requests as two different outputs. Is there a way to combine both Outputstreams or write the request in one single Outputstream?

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking. TCP doesn't know anything about "different outputs", so the server can't know either. Please clarify your question.

Comment: My problem is that I have to send a file through socket and don‘t know how to do this. My request to the server has to look like out.write(...).  But I can‘t send bytes with a printwriter.

Comment: As long as you call `flush()` before you switch between streams/Writers you should be OK.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: not necessarily so. OP -- why not create two connections?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why different connections? One for Printwriter and the other for Outputstream?

Comment: nevermind @JamesKPolk was right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I wasn't certain. Do you have a link to why that's not true?

Comment: @JamesKPolk if you use a stream with buffering, there is a risk of the buffer "stealing" bites upstream to fill the buffer. This is especially true with a BufferedReader.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Ok, I'm not sure that applies for OutputStreams. I know for example ObjectInputStream starts to read ahead right in the constructor, and that can be surprising. I think I'll write an answer that offers a better alternative.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: maybe not on the output streams, but the client will need to read the data